# django model method to behave like a field

Tags: django, django-models

The structure I am trying to achive is,
We have a Foo model, and Foox model.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Foox(models.Model):
    foo = models.Foreignkey(Foo)
    stext = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='description')
    langu = models.ForeignKey(Langutable, verbose_name='Language')
```

I will have Foo models stext field using Foox models, 
When I activate 'en' language, and use Foo's stext field in template or code,

Lets say I used {{ Foo.stext }} in template. value will be determined using
Foox.objects.get(foo=foo,langu = 'en').values('stext')[0]['stext']

if I write foo.stext in my code. My model should know that stext is an attribute and comes from Foox model.

So far, I achieved this using below code for my **unicode**

```
def __unicode__(self):
    stext = ''
    try:
        from panbas.models import Langutable
        langu = Langutable.objects.get(langu='en')
        xtablelookup = '{}{}'.format(self.__class__.__name__.lower(), 'x')
        if xtablelookup in model_util.get_one_to_many_field_names(self.__class__):#I check if there is a Foox model, model_util function does that, returns ['foox']
            stext = self.foox_set.filter(langu=langu).values('stext')[0]['stext']
    except:
        pass
    return '{} {}'.format(self.short_cut, stext)#finally stext came from foox table.
```

Is my approach correct, and are there better ways to do that. I actually need a way to define a field, that queries other models. And doesnt exist in db. Just a placeholder or something.

We have modelmanagers and classmethods, I just cant figure out it.

I know other multilangual approachs and please dont suggest me to use them.

Comment: don't do imports like that, otherwise it'll be imported every time you get the unicode version, which is probably inefficient.

Comment: Thanks @PaulCollingwood , Its just a experiment and will be rewritten if I decide to use this approach.

Comment: It sounds like [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) are what you're looking for.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry , I saw 
https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-replace-django-model-field-property/, but it needs to create those fields in my model. a field not managed by django what I need and than properties maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `@property` decorator, both to retrieve and update the translated value.

```
class Foox(models.Model):
    foo = models.Foreignkey(Foo)
    stext = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='description')
    langu = models.ForeignKey(Langutable, verbose_name='Language')


class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def stext(self):
        return Foox.objects.get(foo=self, langu=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE).stext

    @stext.setter
    def stext(self, value):
        obj = Foox.objects.get_or_create(foo=self, langu=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
        obj.stext = value
        obj.save()
```